# Uninstalled Ubuntu 14.04 from my computer, Windows 8.1 bootloader is all messed up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, multi-boot

I'm coming here for help because I've tried almost every different solution I could find on the internet for any problem that seemed remotely similar.

To give backstory, I have an SSD and a HDD. Recently I decided to give Ubuntu a go and shrunk my HDD partition and installed Ubuntu. Everything was working fine, but after deleting the partitions that Ubuntu were installed on, on reboot I was still booting into GRUB.

This is extremely annoying, and I'm looking to be able to boot straight into Windows again. The only way that I can do this is by going into the boot menu on start up and selecting 'Windows Boot Manager' which is on my SSD (everything works perfectly.)

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get everything back to normal, and GRUB is still there! I've opened my Windows install CD and attempt to rebuild the Windows bootloader, still nothing. When selecting the SSD that Windows is installed on  (M4-CT128M4) it brings me to a screen saying 'Reboot and Select proper Boot device.'

As you can see the boot menu is still detecting two different entries labelled 'Ubuntu', I have no idea what's going on.

Here's an image of my boot menu.

[image]

Comment: You write " I've tried almost every different solution I could find on the internet for any problem that seemed remotely similar." <---- You should list everything you tried and the results. You should've taken notes

Comment: have you tried to understand where is this GRUB loader stored?
For more practical matter you can look to this thread [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall windows with formating hard drive. If it won't work see the text bellow.

Firstly you need to think about what you will doing because you can run out with broken computer. All operating systems after you delete them continue keeping data in your data storage. You can't delete this data without reseting your data storage so you need to  reset your data storage. There are some guides on the internet but i don't remember what i used when i had similar problem. Just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Windows Repair CD and open the command prompt. Run the command

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

That should fix the problem. If it does not work, comment :-)